# How to mock a validator for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a method that validate an Object calling an external service:

```
public void Validate(IValidator<MyType> validator)
{
    IMapper<MyType> mapper = new MyTypeMapper();
    foreach (var element in this.Elements)
    {
        ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(myTypeInstance, mapper, new ValidationConfiguration());

        if (result.IsValid)
            // do something
        else
            // do something else
     }
}
```

Now in my unit test I have a collection of elements. And I want that if an element have a given id number the `Validate` method should return another stub with validation messages:

```
// arrange
var myAggregate aggregate = ElementsNonValidated.Stub();
var mockedValidator = new Mock<IValidator<MyType>>();

mockedValidator.Setup(a => a.Validate(
                 It.Is<Mytype>(x => x.Id == Guid.Parse("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301")),
                 new Mapper(),
                 new ValidationConfiguration()
                )).Returns<ValidationResult>(x => x = new ValidationResult());

// act
myAggregate.Valida(mockedValidator.Object);
```

The problem is: When unit test starts and go forth till the real method validate still return `result=null`. Why? What's wrong with my mock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
mockedValidator.Setup(a => a.Validate(
             It.Is<Mytype>(x => x.Id == Guid.Parse("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301")),
             new Mapper(), 
             new ValidationConfiguration()
            )).Returns<ValidationResult>(x => x = new ValidationResult());
```

You setup `Validate` to expect specific `Mapper` and `ValidationResult` instances, which of course do not match the instances used in your system under test.  If you don't care what instance should be used for a parameter, use `It.IsAny<>`:

```
mockedValidator.Setup(a => a.Validate(
             It.Is<Mytype>(x => x.Id == Guid.Parse("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301")),
             It.IsAny<Mapper>(), 
             It.IsAny<ValidationConfiguration>()
            )).Returns<ValidationResult>(x => x = new ValidationResult());
```

This will return a new `ValidationResult` for any and every invocation to `Validate` where the object's Id is equal to that particular GUID.

---

The reason for the `TargetParameterCountException` is in your `Returns` statement, and is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911124/1698557).

Comment: The null problem (maybe) is resolved. But I get now a Reflection exception: `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch`. What's wrong now? I've setup 3 parameters and I send 3 parameters to the mocked Validate function... :\

Comment: Without a callstack for that exception or more of your code, I can't really say where that might be coming from.  Nothing in your posted code jumps out at me as being wrong.